# What do I need to consider when creating a case?

Tags: case, safety, cooling

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Running in an airtight case.](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/105/running-in-an-airtight-case)

Does it need ventilation? Do I need to use fire-proof materials?