# How can I create a simple case?

Tags: case

How can I create a simple case for my Raspberry Pi?

I don't need an [airtight case](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/105/running-in-an-airtight-case); I'm looking for a simple and cheap case, just to be sure no one touches the circuit board.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The easiest and cheapest case must be [The Punnet](http://www.raspberrypi.org/archives/1310); it is a case made from cardboard. You can download a PDF, print it onto your favourite coloured cardboard, cut it out and stick it together.

Answer (score 8):

Of course, if you have any Lego hanging around that's another easy solution.

In fact, there was an article on the front page of the Raspberry Pi homepage detailing just that: http://www.raspberrypi.org/archives/1354