# Thermal Management in Raspberry Pi Clusters

Tags: cluster

I've been looking through several posts (on the internet) about building Raspberry Pi clusters- and my major question is something rather simple- what about the heat management? Would they overheat when operating as a cluster system (because each Pi is in close proximity with one another)? So is it possible to create a cluster even *without* cooling?

Comment: Can you please state how you want to build the cluster? I have built one and can tell you it very much depends on the details (how close together, encasing of the individual pi, what hosts the whole setup, other devices involved)

Comment: I plan to place them ~5cm atop each other, and ~2cm apart. Encasing is not present as they are placed on a rack, and all of them are connected to a router. Devices are pis and a separate computer which is linked via Ethernet to a router.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless you are using it in an unusually hot environment, I do not think the pi can generate enough heat to hurt itself.  The max temperature is apparently 80 C, and the normal operating temperature 45-55 C.  It does not really require anything in the way of ventilation or cooling, and I've seen a few people report using it in airtight enclosures.

Someone here posted [this prolonged temperature test](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/548/what-is-the-temperature-behaviour-of-a-raspberry-pi-in-an-enclosure/549#549) using a probe in an enclosure.  I have mine in an unventilated case, it's been on for days (mostly idle) and just now `opt/vc/bin/vcgentcmd` reported 53.5 C; this is the on-chip sensor which will be hotter than an external probe.  I maxed the processor (but not the video core) out for 5 minutes and it reported 57.3 C.  The ambient temperature here is ~23 C, although the pi is shoved together with some other warmth generating electronic gear.

My enclosure is actually double -- there's the made for the pi sized (~1.5" deep) plastic case I bought with it screwed inside a wooden box.  I've never noticed the inner plastic case be anything beyond luke warm to the touch.

WRT packing a bunch of them together, I guess it would depend where and how tightly you have them packed, but realistically it seems very unlikely to become an issue.

Comment: A note. The pi is cool a lot of the time due to the large surface area. The largest being the top and bottom. If they are stacked together, even half a centimeter apart, the pi loses its largest surface area for heat dissipation and could cause an exponential curve in the internal temperature

Answer (score 1):

I build a cluster with 16 PI's, and left it 'unventillated'.
After a while, one of them 'died', 
so I had to dismantel the whole cluster to replace the PI.

To avoid this in the futur, I ventillated a little,
and wrote a script to monitor the cluster's temperature.

This is how it works:

description:

16 slave PI's connected to a Master PI (MRPI)
IP add's:
MRPI 192.168.1.70
slaves 71 -- 78 & 81 -- 88

requiered:

SHH installed on all PI's and keys shared both ways,
MRPI to all slaves,
all slaves to MRPI.

on each PI a script to check the T° and send it to the MRPI:

```
#!/bin/bash
mip=`hostname -I`
mip=${mip:10:2}
tfile="/tmp/"$mip".txt" #using the IP add to make a file name
temp=`/opt/vc/bin/vcgencmd measure_temp`
temp=${temp:5:4}
echo $temp >$tfile
#echo $tfile
#cat $tfile
scp $tfile pi@192.168.1.70:$tfile   # SSH won't "cat > " from a script

#################################################################
```

on the MRPI a script to ask the T° of the slaves,
and graphically display the cluster's T°:

```
#!/bin/bash
ssh 192.168.1.71 "./send70temp.sh" >/dev/null
ssh 192.168.1.72 "./send70temp.sh" >/dev/null
ssh 192.168.1.73 "./send70temp.sh" >/dev/null
ssh 192.168.1.74 "./send70temp.sh" >/dev/null
ssh 192.168.1.75 "./send70temp.sh" >/dev/null
ssh 192.168.1.76 "./send70temp.sh" >/dev/null
ssh 192.168.1.77 "./send70temp.sh" >/dev/null
ssh 192.168.1.78 "./send70temp.sh" >/dev/null
ssh 192.168.1.81 "./send70temp.sh" >/dev/null
ssh 192.168.1.82 "./send70temp.sh" >/dev/null
ssh 192.168.1.83 "./send70temp.sh" >/dev/null
ssh 192.168.1.84 "./send70temp.sh" >/dev/null
ssh 192.168.1.85 "./send70temp.sh" >/dev/null
ssh 192.168.1.86 "./send70temp.sh" >/dev/null
ssh 192.168.1.87 "./send70temp.sh" >/dev/null
ssh 192.168.1.88 "./send70temp.sh" >/dev/null

MA=( "/tmp/71.txt" "/tmp/72.txt" "/tmp/73.txt" "/tmp/74.txt" "/tmp/75.txt" "/tmp/76.txt" "/tmp/77.txt" "/tmp/78.txt" )
MA+=( "/tmp/81.txt" "/tmp/82.txt" "/tmp/83.txt" "/tmp/84.txt" "/tmp/85.txt" "/tmp/86.txt" "/tmp/87.txt" "/tmp/88.txt" )
START=1
END=16
HT=35
LT=25
SP=".."
ST=\|\|
clear
for (( p=$HT; p>=$LT; p-- ))
do
    MV=$p" "
    for i in "${MA[@]}"
    do
    LL=`cat $i`
    T=${LL:0:2} # get rid of the decimals
    #echo $T " " $p
    if [ "$p" -gt "$T" ] 
    then
        MV=$MV$SP
    else
        MV=$MV$ST
    fi
    done
echo $MV
done
echo -n "   "
for i in "${MA[@]}"
do
    echo -n  ${i:5:2}
done
echo

#############################################
```

A sample :

```
35 ................................
34 ................................
33 ................................
32 ||............||................
31 ||............||....||||....||||
30 ||||........||||..||||||....||||
29 ||||..||||||||||||||||||||||||||
28 ||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||
27 ||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||
26 ||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||
25 ||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||
   71727374757677788182838485868788
```

Enjoy clustering !!

MuteOn
B6180 Belgium