# Is it a bad idea to do distributed computing?

Tags: hardware, temperature, durability

Like many users, my RPi will be used as a low-consumption micro server and will be powered continuously. All the computing time is not used and could help distributed computing projects like Folding@home or SETI@home, even if the CPU is not designed to do heavy computing.

Is it a bad idea to run a distributed program on the RPi continuously? Even if it cannot shut down like a common computer, will the RPi "shut down" when its CPU reaches its max temperature to prevent overheating? Will it shorten the lifespan of the device?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are [no cooling requirements](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/q/105/40). I think one issue that comes to mind is the SD card, you would have to make sure that you are [following steps to reduce the number of writes](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/q/169/40) to extend it's lifespan.

The only other thing I would add is that the Pi is *slow*. It will offer very little benefit to those organisations alone.  Although it could be argued that if everyone took that stance then there would be no machines connected at all.