# underclocking to prevent overheating in the summer

Tags: hardware

I'm planning on installing my raspberry pi in my garden shed.
I'm living in the Netherlands so very cold winters and occasionally very hot summers.
So I was wondering: does anyone have experience with

1. underclocking the raspberry so that it won't get too hot during the summer
2. changing the cpu speed at run-time so that I can adjust the clockspeed without leaving the house?
3. is it safe to put it in a garden shed? due to heat and humidity

Comment: See also the [question about potential overheating](http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/q/105/114) when running the Pi without ventilation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no need to underclock, unless the temperature in your garden thread gets above 50-60 degrees Celsius. I'm not sure whether you can underclock it dynamically, but there's probably something to do it.

In the garden shed heat should not be a problem. However if the air is humid enough for water to accumulate on it then you may run into some large problems.

I'd say just put it in a case to deal with the dampness unless water would condense on it.

Comment: I would think that with respect to humidity it's good if the Pi is a bit warmer than the environment. That should reduce the condensation.

Answer (score 0):

ModMyPi have the heat sink kits available, but you can just about use any small heat sink from an electronics shop and throw them on. They seem to have gotten a great response; you shouldn't need to under clock the pi at all, and with heat sinks attached could still run it overclocked if necessary.

Comment: If you're going to buy your own heat sinks, shop around got the lowest thermal resistance, to get the best results. Also, it goes without saying, the bigger the surface area of the heat sink, the better the results, but that depends on the case (if any) that you have the pi in.