# Is it safe to run Raspberry Pi in its antistatic bag?

Tags: case

I'm wondering if it is safe to run a Raspberry Pi in its antistatic bag for a short while or some long time?

Also what about heat? Is it possible for Pi to melt the antistatic bag its shipped in?

Comment: Should be fine. See [this question](http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/q/105/40).

Comment: I've got mine pretty confined and it doesn't generate anything beyond "slightly warm" even when stressed.  I dunno how conductive antistatic bags are or are not tho...

Comment: I suggest something more solid, not for heating but for accidental hits, especially if you plug and unplug cables often like I do. After some months of the antistatic bag and a chocolate box, now I [use this case](http://www.teko.it/en/prodotti/famiglia/PO/serie/145) and I had no issue. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Should be fine. Antistatic bags are very slightly conductive, but I doubt you can affect the operation of the RPi with it.

They are typically made from [PET](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polyethylene_terephthalate) which has a melting point of 260°C which is somewhat higher than the lead free solder 232°C, so if you are melting the bag you have other problems!

I used mine in the cardboard box is came in (from farnell/element14) for quite a long time with no problems.

Comment: I was actually looking for an aspirin box to put it in, somehow forgot about its own box. Thanks.

Comment: I ran it in a sealed box, just slightly bigger than the RPi itself [See here](http://codefridge.com/i-built-my-own-raspberry-pi-case/final/). Hottest it's ever gotten was 70'c, but the ambient temp was 34'c. Also I was running nbench for around 3 days.